# Inserting data into multiple tables(f_k linked together) through view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Im trying to insert values through view into two tables which have `f_k Borrower_Id`. But getting an error 'String or binary data would be truncated'.
But same values can get inserted directly without using view.

```
ALTER TRIGGER TRGI_VW_VWORGAN_BOrrower ON vwOrganisationalBorrower
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
insert into OrganisationalBorrower
    select BorrowerID, AccountsDeptAddress
    from inserted
    INSERT INTO OrgContact
    SELECT OrgContactID,borrowerid,ContactDetails,ContactType
    FROM INSERTED


END

--inserting values as below
insert into vwOrganisationalBorrower (BorrowerID,AccountsDeptAddress,OrgContactID,ContactType,ContactDetails) values 
('BR444444','Address','oc999','E','test@gmail')
```

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 13, Procedure TRGI_VW_VWORGAN_BOrrower, Line
>   24 String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Comment: What is the schema of the two underlying tables, and the view definition?

Comment: Did you accidentally swap Type and Details in your second insert statement in the trigger? If so, this is one reason why you should avoid the general laziness of not providing the list of columns to be populated in an insert statement.

Comment: cheers mate. you picked  up my mistake. As im just new with these triggers and was  just trying to my first test insert through views. Can you please tell me one more thing. how it picks Borrower ID for both tables? it doesnt go ambiguous ? please give me a link if you can to increase my knowledge about these views.

Answer (score -1):

I could see you are inserting values to two tables check whether the selection columns are in the same order.

It’s always a best practice to specify the column names that you are inserting to.

Let me know whether this resolves.

Comment: yes im inserting values into two tables through one input . As BorrowerID is primary_key in first table and foreign key in 2nd table. IS my syntax alright as (INSERT INTO VIEW)..........  and 2nd thing order in insert is as it is in Tables.